# WordPress Strange Slider behavior: Blank slide after the last image

Tags: wordpress

I've made a website using WordPress. The problem is the blank slide after the last image. I've checked in Firefox firebug there is not any blank slide or script in code but it is shown in the original site.
Any known solution then help me out.

Comment: provide some code to digest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed you have this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../wp-content/themes/twentyten/js/startstop-slider.js"></script>
```

and then you have the same code again inside that page

```
<div id="detail_slider">
  <script language="javascript">
  ...
  ...
  </script>
```

Try removing that external `startstop-slider.js` file from the page. Maybe they are interfering with each other.

Comment: any help regarding file name n hierarchy will be appreciated as i am using default settings and structure without any changes to files

Comment: removed that file via FTP n problem still exists, did it require any change in doMove() method. As all it is done via WordPress Admin panel.

Comment: It seems to work on my browser when visiting your site. 3 slides rotating, no blank slide anymore.

Comment: working fine in IE, opera but not in FireFox, Thanks a lot for ur help thumbs up

Comment: I'm also using Firefox and it seems fine to me. Try clearing cache. That's what I do a lot when testing pages.